# Riemann-Roch formula for nodal curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be an irreducible, reduced, projective curve over an algebraically closed field, with at worst nodes as singularities. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a trivial vector bundle on $X$ of rank $r$. Consider a short exact sequence of the form $$0 \to \mathcal{F}' \to \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}'' \to 0,$$
where $\mathcal{F}'$ and $\mathcal{F}''$ are coherent, torsion-free sheaves.
What is the formula for $\chi(\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{F}',\mathcal{F}''))$? Is there any reference for this?

I know the answer to the question in the case $X$ is smooth.

Comment: For irreducible (reduced) curves, Riemann-Roch works essentially as in the smooth case: see for instance Hartshorne, ch. IV, exercise 1.9.

Comment: @abx: The exercise only deals with line bundles and does not say anything about coherent sheaves in general.

Comment: We are talking about vector bundles here, aren't we? Then the extension is straightforward, any vector bundle is a successive extension of line bundles.

Comment: Only $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free, I do not know about the rest. I have edited the question. Sorry.